# How can get battery and/or power status to show in the system tray of Windows Server 2008?

Tags: laptop, windows-server-2008, battery, power

How can get a battery and/or power status to show in the system tray of Windows Server 2008?  I want this because this server is actually a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see you battery in Device Manager?
Device Manager is located in Control Panel->System, left menu.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation.  I am currently out of town but will be able to get back to the machine soon and will answer your question then.  Your help is much appreciated.